# Styling the DROPDOWN of a select input

Tags: html, css

I know `select` elements are hard to style, and I know many questions have been asked about them. But the vast majority appear to apply to the styles of either the `select` element itself, or the `option` elements within. Mine is about neither. I want to do two things:

1 - add a border radius to the DROPDOWN (not the `select`, not the `options` - but the dropdown box that appears when you click on the `select`, containing the `option` elements.

2 - remove the vertical scrollbar that Chrome unnecessarily displays on this dropdown box.

Can this be done A) at all, and B) with only CSS and the native `select` element?

Comment: I don't think it's possible as it is styled and displayed by your browser. If you're not restricted to using a `select` tag, you can go for an unordered list, that you can style to whatever you require. Check this out http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ul li** to apply more styles .check the snippet given below and that allows you to perform more styling .

```js
document.getElementById("dmenu").addEventListener("click",function(){
    
    if(document.getElementById("menu").style.display === "none"){
        document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

```css
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 ! important;
  padding:0 ! imortant;
  }
#menu{
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:5px;
  display:none;
  }
li{
  border:1px solid #000;
  background-color:blue;
  color:#fff;
  
  }
li:hover {
  background-color:yellow;
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<select id="dmenu"> </select>
<ul id="menu">Menu
  <li>opt1</li>
  <li>opt2</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are few styles that might meet your need

http://jsfiddle.net/ericrasch/rxqYp/

Adding few snippets from css

```
.styled-select {
   background: url(http://www.ericrasch.com/media/icon-selectbox.png) no-repeat 96% 0;
   height: 29px;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 240px;
}

.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
   font-size: 14px;
   height: 29px;
   padding: 5px; /* If you add too much padding here, the options won't show in IE */
   width: 268px;
}
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully - I want to style the dropdown box that drops down when the select element is clicked, not the select element itself. All your examples have the same style on the dropdown box.

Comment: oh okay!
can u attach a screenshot of what scroll bar you want to remove?